# Serilog with Autofac

Tags: c#, autofac, serilog

I have a logger wrapper and I wanna inject serilog to it with following configurtion perse:

```
var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
   .WriteTo.RollingFile(
      AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetData("DataDirectory").ToString() + "/Log-{Date}.txt")
   .CreateLogger();
```

I cant seem to find a correct way to register it. I want it as singleton. Above is the instance.

I tried registering the instance above. Didnt work. I tried lambda, didnt work.

What works? anyone?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Maybe this helps:

```
builder.Register<ILogger>((c, p) =>
{
    return new LoggerConfiguration()
      .WriteTo.RollingFile(
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetData("DataDirectory").ToString() + "/Log-{Date}.txt")
      .CreateLogger();
}).SingleInstance();
```

Comment: I don't have much time but I can send you link:http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/register/registration.html#selection-of-an-implementation-by-parameter-value

Answer (score 4):

I created a [nuget-package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Serilog.Extensions.Autofac.DependencyInjection) with an extensions method for AutoFac's `ContainerBuilder`.

All you need to do is install it and call the extension with either a logger-configuration or a log-path (and optional a template, you get a default).

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterSerilog("my-log-path"); // or a loggerconfiguration
var container = builder.Build();
var logger = container.Resolve<ILogger<MyClass>>();
logger.LogInformation("Hello World");
```

This also works perfectly with ASP.NET-Core. You find samples and the source-code on the [github-repository](https://github.com/cleancodelabs/Serilog.Extensions.Autofac.DependencyInjection).

Answer (score 2):

There is another Nuget package for Autofac and Serilog integration here:
[Autofac-Serilog integration](https://github.com/nblumhardt/autofac-serilog-integration)

It works well with ASP.NET Core 3.1.
Steps:

1. Install package
2. Create the logger as normal
3. Call `builder.RegisterLogger()` in one of the module or in the `ConfigureContainer()` method of the `Startup.cs` file